# Does ReadString() discard bytes following newline?

Tags: go

I am trying to read from a network connection, in the following way:

```
func getIn(conn net.Conn){
    for{
        in, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
        if err!=nil{
            fmt.Printf(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("[%s]", in)
    }
}
```

The stream of input being sent to that connection is of the following pattern:

> message1\n message2\n message3\n message4\n message5\n

etc...

I noticed that my function skips messages, outputting, for instance,:

> message1\nmessage2\nmessage4\n message5\n

This leads me to think that the bufio ReadString method discards the incoming buffer every time a newline character is encountered. Say the buffer consists of:

> message1\nmess

at the moment of reading. Then, ***message1*** gets read and the remaining part ***mess*** is discarded. This does not entirely make sense either, because then the next input should be ***age2***, but in reality it is ***message3***.

I used a different function, net.Conn.Read(), which indeed does not skip any part of the input, but requires more string parsing on my side. How can I make the ReadString() function work for me?

Comment: Try creating the reader once outside the loop instead of on every iteration. `ReadString` is reading beyond the `\n`, but you lose that buffered data because you keep creaeting a new reader.

Comment: Thank you. That was indeed the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReadString()` doesn't discard data, it is still *buffered* in `bufio.Reader` object, i.e.:

```
conn := bytes.NewBufferString("message1\n message2\n message3\n ")
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)

in, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')                 // "message1\n"
fmt.Println(strconv.Quote(in))
in, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')                  // "message2\n"
fmt.Println(strconv.Quote(in))
fmt.Println(strconv.Quote(conn.String()))        // ""
```

Note that despite all data was drained from `conn` buffer, it is still accessible through subsequent `reader.ReadString()` call. However, you discard your reader object on each iteration, and all data is lost.

You should create buffered readers outside loop, so you'll still have your reader on the second loop:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
for {
    in, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. The name of the NewReader function should have given me a hint as to what it does and why it's there...