# Golang read constant data from TCP Port

Tags: c++, sockets, go, netcat

I've have a process that spits out data to a TCP port in bursts with a few minutes pause between files. I've tried the code below that I've seen on multiple different posts however a large amount (multiple lines worth) of data is lost from the output. I've also tried writing similar code in C++ with the same result. The only reliable way I've found to get all output is to just listen using `nc` but I would like to do this programmatically so that I can use the downtime between bursts in order to separate output into multiple files. Has anyone ran into this issue before? I don't see any pattern to the missing data, just as if some random lines are getting skipped. I even tried to just send the data to a go chan, to see if the print statement was slowing down execution somehow. Any help would be appreciated!

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    arguments := os.Args
    if len(arguments) == 1 {
        fmt.Println("Please provide host:port.")
        return
    }

    CONNECT := arguments[1]
    c, err := net.Dial("tcp", CONNECT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    for {

        message, _ := bufio.NewReader(c).ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Print(message)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know go, but `bufio.NewReader(c)` inside a for loop doesn't look right, especially if buf stands for buffered.

Comment: Create the bufio.Reader outside of the loop. See [Does ReadString() discard bytes following newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309810/does-readstring-discard-bytes-following-newline).   Better yet, use [bufio.Scanner to read lines](https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Lines).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I can not mark comments as answers, however as Cerise Limón pointed out- using a bufio.Scanner() was the solution. The functional code is below. Thank you!

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    arguments := os.Args
    if len(arguments) == 1 {
        fmt.Println("Please provide host:port.")
        return
    }

    CONNECT := arguments[1]
    c, err := net.Dial("tcp", CONNECT)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(c) // Declare outside of the loop
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) 
    }
}
```

Comment: The fix is creating the buffered reader outside of the loop, not the switch to bufio.Scanner.